# Android Studio 3.3 XML Design View not zooming in

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.3

I've been trying to find an editor setting for guidance on fixing this issue. Since I updated to Android Studio 3.3, the zoom function in the design view does not respond to either the zoom in or zoom out clicks.

The only way I've been able to "fix" it, is by detaching the file from the window. All of a sudden it begins to work.

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but I wanted to find out if there is a setting that could cause this, before I submit it ( following the order of [the Android Studio Bug Report page](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs).

Comment: This is obviously a bug, so please submit a bug report, and share the link of your report here

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me from time to time. I used a number of solutions one at a time until the problem was solved.
Possible solutions are:
  1 change the them of the Studio from Darcula to Intellij by click File->Setting->Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance (I got it from others in Stackoverflow).
  2 simply, restart the Studio (I also got it from others in Stackoverflow).
  3 change to full screen mode
Please try your luck

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your bottom toolbar (Run, Logcat, Debug, Build, etc) is **minimized**.

For some reason, when this toolbar is expanded the view is locked at whatever percentage it is currently set to.

This may be a bug, or it may be in place to ensure that you maintain a full view of the XML display view while you are debugging or otherwise using the bottom bar.

Comment: Any luck? I have reproduced this several times on different machines. If my answer allowed you to zoom could you please mark as answered? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have 3.3 and I am able to zoom in/out. Maybe there is some problem with your xml. Please check that.

Comment: should be a comment

Comment: Yes, I know but I am not allowed to comment yet and I thought that it would be converted to a comment as a trivial answer but it didn't.. thanks..

Comment: I disagree with you. This problem should be a bug, not because anything inside xml file. I got this problem too, so often I ran into this SO post